# Enable all GPIO pins on BeagleBone, including the eMMC pins

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, gpio, beagleboard

I'm running Debian Jessie IOT image on a BeagleBone Green.
I like to use the maximum of GPIOs, which is according to the documentation should give me 65 GPIOs.
[GPIOs on BeagleBone Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAtq7.png)

All work except the pins that are shared with the eMMC:
P8_3-6, P8_20-25

So this works:

`config-pin -a P8_7 in+`

This does not work:

`config-pin -a P8_22 in+`

```
bash: /sys/devices/platform/ocp/ocp*P8_22_pinmux/state: No such file or directory 
Cannot write pinmux file: /sys/devices/platform/ocp/ocp*P8_22_pinmux/state
```

Some information.....

```
root@beaglebone:~# cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
0: PF----  -1
1: PF----  -1
2: PF----  -1
3: PF----  -1
4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,cape-universala
```

cape-universala should export all pins
in dmesg is....

```
 [    4.002843] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin 44e10814.0 already requested by 481d8000.mmc; cannot claim for ocp:P8_22_pinmux
 [    4.014528] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin-5 (ocp:P8_22_pinmux) status -22
 [    4.021901] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: could not request pin 5 (44e10814.0) from group pinmux_P8_22_default_pin  on device pinctrl-single
 [    4.034756] bone-pinmux-helper ocp:P8_22_pinmux: Error applying setting, reverse things back
 [    4.089416] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin 44e10814.0 already requested by 481d8000.mmc; cannot claim for ocp:P8_22_pinmux
 [    4.101069] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin-5 (ocp:P8_22_pinmux) status -22
```

I can't seem to disable the eMMC, this is /boot/uEnv.txt

```
  cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet cape_enable=bone_capemgr.enable_partno=cape-universala cape_disable=bone_capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONE-EMMC-2G
```

I am booting the BeagleBone from an sd-card, so the eMMC don't have to be used.

what's wrong?

Comment: Check your Device Tree  for the pin assignments that eMMC uses.  Have you disabled these assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out I was looking to hard... 
This is how to use all of the available GPIO pins:

```
  root@beaglebone:~# more /boot/uEnv.txt | grep -v '#'
  uname_r=4.4.91-ti-r133
  dtb=am335x-boneblack-overlay.dtb
  cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet
```

that's it!

Comment: Also, I needed to get this: apt install bb-cape-overlays

Answer (score 1):

The directory, I am sure you are familiar w/ this procedure, /boot has a file in it called uEnv.txt.

There was an older way to adjust settings and it may still apply. This application of commenting uncommenting the eMMC part to the uEnv.txt file should allow you to use those specific pins for use.

Now...**please listen**.

I have done this before and have not been able to boot from my eMMC once I have uncommented, remove the # mark, the eMMC. I know that you are using an SD Card. I can test it real quickly and get back to you.

I just wanted to let you know that this exists and that uboot overlays in newer Debian images are what is done now. So, I am pretty sure that we do not use device tree overlays on specific Debian Distros. I guess it all depends on what kernel you have and what image you have booted on your machine.

Um...I have my machine plugged in now and I am about to test the SD Card support after I changed my /boot directory file uEnv.txt to uncomment the eMMC portion to the file. I am using Linux beaglebone 4.4.91-ti-r136 on my machine for compatibility w/ Adafruit_BBIO's PWM.

In that file, the uEnv.txt file in the /boot directory, I had to uncomment this section: **disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1**.

I am about to reboot.

Okay...I was able to boot w/ uncommenting the **disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1** portion to the uEnv.txt file.

This should open up the pins. I will test it really quickly.

Seth

P.S. https://github.com/mvduin/bbb-pin-utils is a good utility for showing pins that are available.

[This is the photo of my print out using that utility for the pins.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1S20.jpg)

Comment: thanks Seth ... I tried various boot options in the uEnv.txt but none work. Can you post your complete uEnv.txt please? thank you

Comment: Okay...give me a couple of days or by tomorrow. I am sorry for the late reply. Seth

Comment: Hello...the damn site says I cannot post any longer (too many poor comments or something). Sorry. Seth

Answer (score 1):

Latest Image, uname: 4.9.78-ti-r94 and ignore all overlay stuff

Oo a fresh new image, I enabled all GPIO's on Rail:P8 & P9 
just by changing the uEnv. See #mco comments. Those are the only changes

```
#uboot_overlay_addr2=/lib/firmware/<file2>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr3=/lib/firmware/<file3>.dtbo
###
###Additional custom capes
#uboot_overlay_addr4=/lib/firmware/<file4>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr5=/lib/firmware/<file5>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr6=/lib/firmware/<file6>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr7=/lib/firmware/<file7>.dtbo
###
###Custom Cape
#dtb_overlay=/lib/firmware/<file8>.dtbo
###
###Disable auto loading of virtual capes (emmc/video/wireless/adc)
disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
disable_uboot_overlay_video=1
disable_uboot_overlay_audio=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_wireless=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_adc=1
###
###PRUSS OPTIONS
###pru_rproc (4.4.x-ti kernel)
### mco-mco

# uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-4-TI-00A0.dtbo

###pru_uio (4.4.x-ti & mainline/bone kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-UIO-00A0.dtbo
###
###Cape Universal Enable
enable_uboot_cape_universal=1
###
###Debug: disable uboot autoload of Cape
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr0=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr1=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr2=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr3=1
###
###U-Boot fdt tweaks... (60000 = 384KB)
#uboot_fdt_buffer=0x60000
###U-Boot Overlays###

cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet omap_wdt.nowayout=0

#In the event of edid real failures, uncomment this next line:
#cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 quiet video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e

##Example v3.8.x
#cape_disable=capemgr.disable_partno=
#cape_enable=capemgr.enable_partno=

##Example v4.1.x
#cape_disable=bone_capemgr.disable_partno=
#cape_enable=bone_capemgr.enable_partno=

##enable Generic eMMC Flasher:
##make sure, these tools are installed: dosfstools rsync
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh

# mco-mco
### optargs=quiet capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
### optargs=quiet capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI,BB-BONELT-HDMIN

#dtb=am335x-boneblack-emmc-overlay.dtb
```

Then I am executing a script at boot to 'debunk' the pwm's system files which can change between reboots. This script generates /tmp/gpiossetup and aligns the pwm pins correct.

```
#!/bin/bash
ERRORF=/tmp/pwmerrors.txt
PWMF=/tmp/pwmsetup
[[ -f $PWMF ]] && exit
echo > $PWMF
sync
pushd /sys/class/pwm
idx=0
pwms=(20000     20000    20000    20000    20000    20000    20000)
dutys=( 0       0        0        0        0        0        0)
expo=(  0       1        0        1        0        1        0)
right=(48302200 48302200 48300100 48300200 48300200 48304200 48304200)
for p in P9.14  P9.16    P9.42    P9.21    P9.22    P8.13    P8.19;do
    config-pin $p pwm
    for link in $(ls -l | awk '{print $11}');do
        if [[ $link =~ ${right[$idx]} ]];then
            #echo $link
            #echo "sys folder for $p is $(echo $link | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')"
            sysfld=$(echo $link | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')
            pushd $sysfld
                echo ">"$(pwd)   exporting: ${expo[$idx]}"<"
                ex=${expo[$idx]}
                echo $ex > unexport
        sync
                echo $ex > export
                if [[ -d "pwm$ex" ]];then
                    echo $(pwd) $p  $ex >> $PWMF
                    echo ${pwms[$idx]} > "pwm$ex/period"
                    echo ${dutys[$idx]} > "pwm$ex/duty_cycle"
                    echo "1" > "pwm${ex}/enable"
                    #echo $(pwd)/pwm$ex/
                else
                    echo "? cannot export ($pwd)" >> $ERRORF
                fi
            popd
        fi
        sleep 0.2
    done
    idx=$((idx+1))
    sleep 0.2
done
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

Just un-comment below line in /boot/uEnv.txt and reboot.

```
#disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
```

to

```
disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
```

This will disable emmc and free-up all pins allocated for emmc. Note that you have run beaglebone from SD card.